# Matrices with eigenvalues 0 and 1

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can you describe all $2\times 2$ matrices whose eigenvalues are 0 and 1?

My attempt: 
I know that 0 and 1 has to be solutions of the characteristic polynomial. And I've considered some examples like $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} \text{ etc.}$$but I haven't found any regularity. But I also know from linear algebra that a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2=A$ has only eigenvalues 0 and/or 1. Are there any more matrices? What do they have to satisfy?

Comment: Do you mean that "the matrix has two eigenvalues, which are 0 and 1" or "the matrix has some unknown number of eigenvalues, all of which are either 0 or 1"?

Comment: @Sharkos I would be interested in both cases :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can easily work out the characteristic polynomial, which is
$$
X^2 - (a+d)X + (ad-bc)
$$
Based on your information, you have
$$
\begin{cases}
a+d=1 \\
ad-bc=0
\end{cases}
$$
because in a polynomial $X^2+pX+q$ the sum of the roots is $-p$ and their product is $q$.

This gives $d=1-a$, so $a-a^2-bc=0$ or $bc=a-a^2$. You can thus choose arbitrarily $a$. If $a=0$ or $a=1$, then one among $b$ and $c$ must be zero and the other one is arbitrary. For $a-a^2\ne0$, the matrices you look for have the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
\dfrac{a-a^2}{b} & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So the general form is one of these five cases

1. $\begin{bmatrix}0 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\quad$ (arbitrary $b$)
2. $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ c & 1\end{bmatrix}\quad$ (arbitrary $c$)
3. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad$ (arbitrary $b$)
4. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ c & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad$ (arbitrary $c$)
5. $\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b \\
   \dfrac{a-a^2}{b} & 1-a
   \end{bmatrix}\quad$ ($a\ne0$, $a\ne1$, $b\ne0$)

Answer (score 5):

Since the eigenvalues are 0 and 1 (hence distinct), the matrix must be diagonalizable.  Thus it must be of the form $P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}P$ for some invertible matrix $P$.  Since there is a nice explicit formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, you can work out the form of any matrix of the aforementioned form.  Take $P = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, where $\det P = ad-bc \ne 0$, then write out $P^{-1}$, and then compute.

EDIT: I am assuming you mean that the set of eignevalues of your matrix must be $\{0,1\}$, as opposed to being contained in this set, which is what Sharkos assumes.  So it depends on what you intended.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that we exclude matrices from having complex eigenvalues but no real eigenvalues (which seems reasonable given your question) we make use of the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the matrix.

There is some invertible matrix $P$ (a *change of basis*) such that

$$A = P^{-1} J P$$

where $J$ is in *Jordan normal form* with either $0$ or $1$ on the diagonal. In particular,

$$J = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}$$

generate all other forms of these matrices.

- The first case has $A=0$.
- The second case has $A=I$.
- The third case is a change-of-basis from having one of each eigenvalue; it is a projection onto a line.
- The fourth case is a nilpotent matrix such that $A^2=0$. It maps one direction into another, and that direction into oblivion.
- The fifth case generates a skew/shear in some direction.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer that suggests how to parametrize such matrices explicitly.

The other answers are more elegant and tell the story more succinctly, but they construct the answers non-uniquely.  (There are different matrices that you can conjugate a given Jordan normal form by and still obtain the same matrices:  $P^{-1} J P = Q^{-1} J Q$ is possible with $P \ne Q$.)

---

First a little result about the characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I)$ for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$:
$$
p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A) \lambda + \det A,
$$
where $\operatorname{tr} A = a + d$ is the trace.  Check this from the definition if you're not familiar with it.

Now, proceed by cases.  **Suppose that $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue.**  Then,
$$
p_A(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^2 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1.
$$
So, we know that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr} A &= 2 \\
\det A &= 1
\end{align}
\right.
$$
With
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
a + d &= 2 \\
ad - bc &= 1
\end{align}
\right..
$$
Taking advantage of the trace equation to reduce the number of parameters, let's make the substitution $a = 1 + t$ and $d = 1 - t$.  Now the determinant equation becomes $(1 + t)(1 - t) - bc = 1$ or
$$
bc = t^2.
$$
Either $b = 0$, in which case, $t = 0$, as well, and $c$ is free to take any value:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ c & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Or $b \ne 0$, so $c = -\frac{t^2}{b}$, so we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 + t & b \\ -\tfrac{t^2}{b} & 1 + t \end{bmatrix}.
$$

The space of possibilities in $(b, c)$-plane consists of both axes (corresponding to having $t = 0$, hence $1$ on the diagonal) together with the second and fourth quadrants (corresponding to $t \ne 0)$.

---

A similar analysis can give an explicit description of the other cases for the possibilities of the eigenvalues.  (Note that this idea generalizes beyond your $\lambda \in \{0, 1\}$ assumption.)

Comment: I think the second instance of $P$ near the top of your answer should be $Q$.

Comment: Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ has only eigenvalues $0$
and $1$ then its characteristic polynomial is of the form 
$$
z^{a}\left(z-1\right)^{b}=z^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{b}\left(\begin{array}{c}
b\\
k
\end{array}\right)z^{k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{b}\left(\begin{array}{c}
b\\
k
\end{array}\right)z^{a+k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}
$$
 with $a+b=n$. A matrix that has the above characteristic polynomial
is
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &  &  &  &  & -c_{0}\\
1 & 0 &  &  &  & -c_{1}\\
 & 1 & 0 &  &  & -c_{2}\\
 &  & 1 & \ddots &  & \vdots\\
 &  &  & \ddots & 0 & -c_{n-2}\\
 &  &  &  & 1 & -c_{n-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where
$$
c_{j}=\begin{cases}
0 & j<a\\
\left(\begin{array}{c}
b\\
k
\end{array}\right)\left(-1\right)^{n-k} & j\geq a
\end{cases}.
$$
The above is called the Frobenius companion matrix to the characteristic
polynomial. Another matrix that will satisfy this is $B^{T}$ since
$\det\left(X^{T}\right)=\det\left(X\right)$. Note that $B$ is not a projection (i.e. $B^2\neq B$).

Obviously, not all matrices
that have only eigenvalues of $0$ and $1$ are of this form. For
example, $I$ only has $1$ as an eigenvalue but cannot be written
in the above form.

Comment: This construction gives (up to conjugation) the matrices which have the polynomial as minimal polynomial.